# Cannot seem to fetch SSM Parameter at deploy with CDK

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm currently trying a fetch a parameter for my pipeline through the CDK SSM Parameter library, however I seem to face a weird issue:

```
CfnParameter at 'nonProdAccountId.Parameter' should be created in the scope of a Stack, but no Stack found
```

However, I'm rather confident that I am fetching my Parameter value in the Scope of a Stack (the `BackendPipelineStack`).

```
//cdk.ts aka my entrypoint
const app = new cdk.App()
...
new BackendPipelineStack(app, "BackendPipelineStack", {
  nonProdAccountId: StringParameter.fromStringParameterName(app, "nonProdAccountId", "nonProdAccountId").stringValue,
  apiStack,
  commonInfraStack,
  deploymentStack,
})
```

Am I missing something?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you're importing the StringParameter in the scope of the App. The first argument in every `Stack` or `Construct` is the scope.

You can create stacks in the scope of an App, but you can't create constructs in the scope of an App - they have to be created in the scope of a Stack.

You need to move the import into the stack, and use the stack as the scope for the import (passing `this` instead of `app`).

So you would change

```
  nonProdAccountId: StringParameter.fromStringParameterName(app, "nonProdAccountId", "nonProdAccountId").stringValue,
```

to

```
  nonProdAccountIdParamName: "nonProdAccountId",
```

And import the parameter inside of the stack with

```
const nonProdAccountId = new StringParameter.fromStringParameterName(this, "nonProdAccountId", nonProdAccountIdParamName).stringValue;
```

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you mean.
Very smart workaround, thanks a lot for your help!